# IntelliJ Global Library & Global VM Options Question

Tags: intellij-idea

I have been trying to achieve two things in IntelliJ project settings which have thus far been unsuccessful.

I am using the IDE for Java programming, and I am trying to add a global library (JavaFX) that automatically applies to (or can at least be set as a library that can be referenced by) the project at hand. The second thing I am attempting to do is add VM options that would apply to every project (or at least be set in a place where they can be referenced to by the current project.) This is because my JavaFX will not work without the VM options.

I have attempted to set the lib folder of the library I am attempting to make global as a global library in IntelliJ. The result has been an issue where IntelliJ would not allow me to reference the material in the lib without copying it to the current project. When I copy it, however, it says that the project lib copy is not being used, and I still do not have access to the lib material.

For the VM options, I have attempted to add the options to the shared build process VM options under Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler. The result has been simply that the VM options do not appear. This one was more of a guess by me, so I'm not surprised it didn't work.

Any advice? Is this simply not possible? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a Global Library for JavaFX and then add this library to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency) of the existing project.

VM options should probably go for the run configurations instead of the compiler, so you need to edit the defaults/templates for the run configurations. If you want it to apply for all the new projects, you can set it here:

[image: new projects]

Comment: I tried both of these and your suggestion for the VM options worked perfectly! I am having some trouble with the global libraries, as setting the module as a dependency seems to convince the IDE that JavaFX code is syntactically valid, but upon compiling it claims there are missing runtime components. I also seem to be having a new issue with several test classes I've been making which just output "Hello World!" The IDE is throwing me:

 Error: Could not find or load main class test.test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.test

Comment: Glad to help, you may also consider saving a project as a template feature: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/saving-project-as-template.html.